# HWUT state machine walkers example

Tags: unit-testing

Can someone share with me an example of state machine walkers? I have been looking in the documentation, but the example of door state is incomplete. Otherwise, can someone recommend any other tool to create this kind of testing?

Answer (score 0):

The HWUT source code distribution contains unit test examples in 
the test on itself. You find the minimalist iterator example in the 
source tree of HWUT as shown below:

Directory:

```
    $HWUT_PATH/support/C/TEST
```

Files:

```
    Makefile, test-hwut_sm_walker*.c
```